# How to prove a continuous bijection on a compact set is a homeomorphism?

Tags: analysis

Let $E\in R^n$ be a compact set. $f$ is a continuous bijection on $E$. Try to prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism from $E$ to $f(E)$.

Comment: Show that the image of a closed set is closed.